# R: How to loop or lapply over rows in one df and use the information in another df

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, testing, lapply

I have a df with testcases (eg if X = 1 and Y=0 then cat= '3'), and an additional dataframe with values to be tested

```
df <- data.frame('tc' = c('X==1 & Y!=1 ','X==0 & Y!=1','X==1 & Y==1'), "cat" = 1:3)
Data <- data.frame(X = c('1','0', '1','1', '1'), Y = c('1','0', '1','0', '1'))
```

I can currently only test for one testcase at the time by using

```
#first testcase
Data <- within(Data, cat_test <- ifelse((X==1 & Y!=1 ), paste(df$cat[1]), 0))
table(Data$cat_test )

#second testcase
Data <- within(Data, cat_test <- ifelse((X==0 & Y!=1 ), paste(df$cat[2]), Data$cat_test))
table(Data$cat_test )

#...and so on...
```

I would like to use lapply or similar to loop over the dataframe and test each testcase, something like

```
Data <- within(Data, test <- ifelse(paste(df$tc), paste(df$cat), Data$test))
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a string containing code to compute the category and then parse and evaluate it.  We assume that the conditions are mutually exclusive (which is the case in the question) and that the default value if none of the conditions are TRUE is 0 (but there are no such cases in the question). No packages are used.

```
txt <- with(df, paste( sprintf("%d*(%s)", cat, tc), collapse = "+"))
transform(Data, cat = eval(parse(text = txt)))
```

giving:

```
  X Y cat
1 1 1   3
2 0 0   2
3 1 1   3
4 1 0   1
5 1 1   3
```

Note that `txt` is:

```
> txt
[1] "1*(X==1 & Y!=1 )+2*(X==0 & Y!=1)+3*(X==1 & Y==1)"
```

If the conditions are not mutually exclusive and the first that is true should be reported use this as `txt`.  If none are TRUE it uses NA as the category.

```
txt <- with(df, sprintf("c(%s)[max.col(cbind(%s,1) == 1, 'first')]",
  toString(cat), toString(tc)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this like that:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  mutate(cat = case_when(X == 1 & Y != 1 ~ 1,
                         X == 0 & Y != 1 ~ 2,
                         X == 1 & Y == 1 ~ 3))
```

The result is:

```
  X Y cat
1 1 1   3
2 0 0   2
3 1 1   3
4 1 0   1
5 1 1   3
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that my df contains more than 50 testcases, so I need a way to use the information within the df, else I would have to list them all up?

Comment: If you do not want to write the `case_when()`'s body by yourself you can use this and just paste it: `df %>% transmute(extracted = paste0(tc, " ~ ", cat, ","))`.

Comment: That would work, except that I need the information within the df on the additional df 'Data'.  And this does not work: data %>% transmute(extracted = paste0(df$tc, " ~ ", df$cat, ","))